# ISDATE() datetime string with offset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to check if a value is a date, however the `ISDATE()` function return 0 when confronted with a value like `2012-07-21 00:00:00+02:00` because of the offset. My problem is that I cant simply cast the value, in fact `ISDATE()` is intended to be used in the query to check if the value is a date before casting (see example below).

```
SELECT p.propertyid 
FROM   property p 
WHERE  CASE Isdate(p.[value]) 
         WHEN 1 THEN 
           CASE 
             WHEN Cast(p.[value] AS DATETIME) >= Cast('7/1/2012' AS DATETIME) 
           THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END 
         ELSE 0 
       END = 1
```

So I would like to know how to check if the `p.[value]` in the example is a date.

Comment: You can't rely on this check to make cast work anyway, there is no guarantee that the check will happen first. There are plenty of examples here that should serve as a warning about relying on this type of logic: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/does-sql-server-read-all-of-a-coalesce-function-even-if-the-first-argument-is-no

Comment: Why do you need to make an ISDATE test on a value of a column called `enddate`? Are there actual non-date values? I'm not asking why they are there (even though I might and perhaps should), but I would be interested to know what they look like.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in the example, the actual column name is "value" and it doesn't always contain a date, edited the example to fix this.

Comment: All right, it's not purely a date column, which begs another question, yet I'll refrain. I'm still interested to know what kind of other data the `value` column may contain. Could you give some examples?

Answer (score -2):

SQL Server 2012 makes this easy.

```
select p.propertyid from Property p 
where try_convert(datetyime,p.[enddate])  is not null
```

Comment: -1, for a mean answer. SQL Server '08 is tagged, showing him what '12 does isn't helpful.